# Cannot find any information on property 'userName' in a bean of type 'com.home.homeapp.actionform.LoginForm'

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, ide, jboss

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE, JBOSS v5.0, java version 1.5.0_16 and MySQL v5.1.0 for my application. I am trying to Authenticate to the application using Bean and Servlet In JSP.

My Steps:

Step:1 Create a web page  "login.jsp"  to login the user.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="loginbean.jsp">
<br><br>
<table align="center"><tr><td><h2>Login Authentication</h2></td></tr></table>
<table width="300px" align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000;background-color:#efefef;">
<tr><td colspan=2></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2> </td></tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b>Login Name</b></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="userName" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b>Password</b></td>
  <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan=2> </td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Step:2 To create a "loginbean.jsp" to set the parameter of the login.

```
<%@ page language="Java" import="java.sql.*" %>  
<HTML> 
<HEAD><TITLE>DataBase Search</TITLE></HEAD>  
<BODY>
<jsp:useBean id="db" scope="request" class="logbean.LoginBean" >
  <jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value="<%=request.getParameter("userName")%>"/>
  <jsp:setProperty name="db" property="password" value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>"/>
 </jsp:useBean>
<jsp:forward page="hello">
  <jsp:param name="username" value="<%=db.getUserName()%>" />
  <jsp:param name="password" value="<%=db.getPassword()%>" />
</jsp:forward> 
</body>
</html>
```

Step:3 To create a "LoginBean.java" to mapping the parameter of  "loginbean.jsp".

```
package logbean;
public class LoginBean {
  String userName="";
  String password="";
  public String getUserName() {
  return userName;
  }
  public void setUserName(String userName) {
  this.userName = userName;
  }
  public String getPassword() {
  return password;
  }
  public void setPassword(String password) {
 this.password = password;
  }
  }
```

Step:4 To create a  Servlet "login.java" for validate the user login.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class login extends HttpServlet{ 
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException,IOException{
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
  Connection conn = null;
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
  String dbName = "user_register";
  String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String userName = "root"; 
  String password = "root";
 String username="";
 String userpass="";
 String strQuery= ""; 
  Statement st=null;
  ResultSet rs=null;
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
  try {
  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
  if(request.getParameter("username")!=null &&
     request.getParameter("username")!="" && request.getParameter("password")!=null &&
     request.getParameter("password")!="")
  {
  username = request.getParameter("username").toString();
  userpass = request.getParameter("password").toString();
  strQuery="select * from userregister where 
    username='"+username+"' and  password='"+userpass+"'";
 System.out.println(strQuery);
  st = conn.createStatement();
  rs = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
  int count=0;
  while(rs.next())
  {
  session.setAttribute("username",rs.getString(2));
  count++;
  }
  if(count>0)
  {
  response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
  }
  else
  {
 response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
  }
  }
  else
  {
 response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
  }
  System.out.println("Connected to the database"); 
  conn.close();
  System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
}
```

Step :5 To create the webpage "welcome.jsp" to display the message after successful message.

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD><TITLE>Welcome</TITLE></HEAD>  
<BODY>
<br><br><br><br>
<table align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
<%
if(session.getAttribute("username")!=null && session.getAttribute("username")!="")
{
String user = session.getAttribute("username").toString();
%>
<tr><td align="center"><h1>Welcome <b><%= user%></b></h1></td></tr>
<%
}
%>
</table>
</body>
<html>
```

BUT WHILE RUNNING THE APPLICATION FOLLOWING ERROR IS COMING:

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'userName' in a bean of type 'com.home.homeapp.actionform.LoginForm'
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.handleSetProperty(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:667)
    org.apache.jsp.loginbean_jsp._jspService(loginbean_jsp.java:66)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'userName' in a bean of type 'com.home.homeapp.actionform.LoginForm'
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getWriteMethod(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:795)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.handleSetProperty(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:664)
    org.apache.jsp.loginbean_jsp._jspService(loginbean_jsp.java:66)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA logs.

PLEASE HELP ME OUT.

Regards
Bijoy

Comment: welcome to SO.  When entering code in a post, make sure it is indented 4 spaces so it will format correctly.  Either indent it before pasting, or hilight the code and use the `{}` button in the editor.  I took care of it for you on this post.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cannot find any information on property 'userName' in a bean 
of type 'com.home.homeapp.actionform.LoginForm'
```

It looks more like a problem with your JSPs. Bean property names
begin with lowercase letters (unless you expend considerable effort to
make it otherwise). It is potentially confusing that the initial
lowercase letter by convention appears uppercase in getter and setter
names; for example, `getEmpName()` and `setEmpName(String)` would be the
getter and setter for property `"empName"`.

If Jasper couldn't find the bean class then it would have said so; if it
goes so far as to check the presence of a particular property then it
has already introspected the bean class.

Doesnt matter if you created your properties in uppercase, but I recommend you that you have to makesure that property is in lower case.

```
public String getShipmentHeaderID() {
        return ShipmentHeaderID;
    }

    public void setShipmentHeaderID(String _ShipmentHeaderID) {
        ShipmentHeaderID = _ShipmentHeaderID;
    }

    public String getShipmentHeaderNumber() {
        return ShipmentHeaderNumber;
    }

    public void setShipmentHeaderNumber(String _ShipmentHeaderNumber) {
        ShipmentHeaderNumber = _ShipmentHeaderNumber;
    }


<td width="20%"><jsp:getProperty name="pBean" property="shipmentHeaderID" /></td>

<td width="20%"><jsp:getProperty name="pBean" property="shipmentHeaderNumber" /></td>
```